# How do I get more than one keyboard input at a time in Small Basic

Tags: keyboard-events, smallbasic

I thought this would work, but didn't

```
GraphicsWindow.KeyDown = KeyDown

Sub KeyDown
   If GraphicsWindow.LastKey = "W" And GraphicsWindow.LastKey = "Space" Then
      Do Stuff
   EndIf
EndSub
```

I need a solution to this so I can get more than one keyboard input at a time from a user

Answer (score 2):

Here you go! This should do what you need!

```
GraphicsWindow.KeyDown = KeyDown
GraphicsWindow.KeyUp = KeyUp

While 1 = 1
Program.Delay(10)
If Key["Space"] = "True" And Key["Up"] Then
 TextWindow.WriteLine("DOING STUFF!")
EndIf
EndWhile


Sub Keydown
LastKeyDown = GraphicsWindow.LastKey
Key[LastKeyDown] = "True"
EndSub

Sub KeyUp
LastKeyUp = GraphicsWindow.LastKey
Key[LastKeyUp] = "False"
EndSub
```

Comment: right but it wont always be space and up, what happens if he wants it to be with any key?

Comment: Pretty simple, Just replace the key inside the quotes to what you need: Key["W"] Or Key["Control"]

Comment: erm, right but lets say your playigna  top view gta style game - you got diaganals as well, that makes to 4 moves (coortesian plane movement,) and 4 diaganoles, so you will have to have 8 if statements correct? is there any way to make it more effiecient? and how would you just debug that (just wodnering cuz i doa lot of debugging?)